# "Pixmap" migration on Gtk 3

Tags: python, gtk

I have a python 2 project using GTK2. 
I am working on this project to migrate python 2 to python 3 and Gtk2 to Gtk 3.
I have a problem with the Gtk migration.
I want to replace “gdk. Pixmap” in my code.
I found this [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/migrating-2to3.html#replace-gdkpixmap-by-cairo-surfaces):

> Replace GdkPixmap by cairo surfaces The GdkPixmap object and related
> functions have been removed. In the Cairo-centric world of GTK 3,
> Cairo surfaces take over the role of pixmaps.

I have to use Cairo, but I don’t know how. 
I spent a lot of time looking for examples in python.
 I didn’t find anything that matched my code.
Can someone help me, give me references?

```
Python2 :

class TraceView(gtk.DrawingArea):

     …

    def configure_event(self, widget, event):
        _, _, width, height = widget.get_allocation()
        self.pixmap = Pixmap(widget.window, width, height)
        self.pixmap.draw_rectangle(widget.get_style().white_gc, True, 0, 0, width, height)
        ...
        return True

    def expose_event(self, widget, event):
        x, y, width, height = event.area
        widget.window.draw_drawable(widget.get_style().fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL],
                                    self.pixmap, x, y, x, y, width, height)
        self.maj_exposed()
        ...
        return False

Python3 :

class TraceView(Gtk.DrawingArea):

     …

    def configure_event(self, widget, event):
        width = widget.get_allocated_width()
        height = widget.get_allocated_height()
        self.pixmap = ?
        self.pixmap. … ?
        ...
        return True

    def draw(self, widget, event):
        ???
        self.maj_exposed()
        ...
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example of gtk3 program that draws a rectangle

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MinimalCairoTest(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MinimalCairoTest, self).__init__()
        self.set_size_request(400, 400)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        darea = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        darea.connect("draw", self.__draw_cb)
        self.add(darea)
        self.show_all()

    def __draw_cb(self, widget, cairo_context):
        cairo_context.set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        cairo_context.rectangle(20, 20, 120, 80)
        cairo_context.fill()


MinimalCairoTest()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

You can find more examples about how to draw with cairo here https://seriot.ch/pycairo/ and documentation here https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/context.html

Comment: Thank you, this example helped me. So, I think that the content of configure_event (creation of Pixmap) is no longer useful ?

Comment: In Gtk 3 you have a event 'size-allocate' where you get the widget dimensions. Maybe you can create a cairo surface (instead of  a pixmap) to use as a cache if you draw is complex and then copy it on the cantext received in the draw event. But I am not sure if I understand your use case